# Copying Numbers Into a Single Cell Then Splitting Into Rows

Tags: google-sheets

I am copying and pasting algo numbers into Google Sheets but doing quite a bit of work by hand.  The numbers I copy looks like this: 16957.25 16679.75 16268.75 16072.5 15695.5 15447.5 15203.75 14801.25 14695.25 14490.5 13891.0 13076.25 12984.25.  Of course these numbers are all pasted in the same cell.  I then split each entry into its own cell in Column A.  Is there a faster way?

Comment: from https://zapier.com › blog › split-text-excel-zapier
How to Split Text in Excel, Google Sheets, and Your Other ...
Select the text or column, then click the Data menu and select Split text to columns.... Google Sheets will open a small menu beside your text where you can select to split by comma, space, semicolon, period, or custom character. Select the delimiter your text uses, and Google Sheets will automatically split your text.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. _I am copying and pasting algo numbers into Google Sheets_ Would you please explain what you are copying the numbers "from". Are they in a file, would you provide a sample of the file content.

Answer (score 1):

you could even use a calculation, something like:

```
=SPLIT(A1," ")
```

This will split the text horizontally into cells. If you want to get it vertically instead, apply this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ")
```